# Fixing ImportError with pyWin32 on ServiceManager Preparation

Tags: python, pywin32, servicemanager

My program is using the latest version of Python 3.8 + pywin32, but when I run it gets an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:ServiceDenoise_1.0.0.3045DenoiseServiceCreate.py", line 75, in <module>
servicemanager. PrepareToHostSingle(Win32IPSService)
AttributeError: module 'servicemanager' has no attribute 'PrepareToHostSingle'
```

What's going on?

I tried uninstalling the `pywin32` module and `servicemanager`, but it didn't work, in the `servicemanager.py` for `PrepareToHostSingle` is like this:

```
def PrepareToHostSingle(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown

 Is there any good idea to fix it
```

Comment: Where did you get your `servicemanager.py` file containing `def PreparateToHostSingle`? (Please post a link.) https://github.com/hmrc/service-manager doesn't contain anything like PreparateToHostSingle.

Comment: I downloaded pywin32 using conda, which includes Servicemanager

Comment: As I asked, please post a link to servicemanager.py. You may want to use pastebin.cometc. if it's long.